# Why doesn't my attempt to escape quotation marks in JSON work?

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

I am parsing a JSON-string with the JQuery.parseJSON function, as I have done lot's of times in my code. On this particular case, though, I get: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token R`. The only upper case R that exists, in my JSON-formatted String, comes right after an escaped quotation mark, `... \"R ...` like this. It seems like too much of a coincidence to be caused by anything other than this, but as far as I can tell, I have completely followed the proper syntax as described on json.org.

**EDIT:**

I've tried to manually remove the occurrances of `\"` in a hardcoded test, and the string formats perfectly into a proper Javascript object. In other words, my `\"` is definitely the problem here...

```
var myObject = $.parseJSON(myString);
```

**EDIT 2:**

the problematic area of my String is here displayed, both in working, and not working condition. first the problematic one:

```
{"lineID":33,"boxID":10,"title":"My text with the \"Ruining Part\""}
```

Then the working one:

```
{"lineID":33,"boxID":10,"title":"My text with the Ruining Part"}
```

Finally how i format my javabean object into JSON string.

```
String jsonObjectAsString = new Gson().toJson(myJavaBeanObject);
```

Comment: Show us your whole JSON message

Comment: Posting the JSON string causing this will help.

Comment: How are you creating the JSON in the first place? Are you using a library function or something home-grown?

Comment: My whole JSON string is very long, and possibly contains sensitive information. But I'll put in an edit of the problematic area in a question edit update. I am using Gson to format from JavaBean object.

Comment: Double escape it as in GregL's answer. i.e. `\\"Ruining Part\\"`

Comment: Quick question. How can I double escape it? I mean the strings are read from a database, they are not hardcoded except for in my troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to escape the backslash in your string, if it is hardcoded, so that the final string that gets parsed has a single backslash followed by a double quote. Otherwise, the browser thinks you are trying to escape a double quote in your string, which does nothing.

So change your string to:

```
...\\"R...
```

Comment: +1 - Exactly - `JSON.parse('{"hello":"This is a \"String"}')` returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token S` whereas `JSON.parse('{"hello":"This is a \\"String"}')` correctly parses the JSON string passed.

Comment: I do not completely understand. My String before parsing to JSON format is `My text with the "Ruining Part"`. Formatted by Gson, it becomes `My text with the \"Ruining Part\"`. Shouldn't it be `My text with the "Ruining Part"` again when it is parsed into an object in javascript again automatically? Or is there a mismatch inbetween Gson and javascripts way of parsing?

And your suggestion, wouldn't it escape the Gson generated reversed solidus, and do nothing to escape the actually quotation mark?

Comment: When you just use \", that \ will be consumed by JavaScript's string parser (as the escape character for the " character) and the JSON parser will just get the ". But when you use \\", the JavaScript string parser consumes one \ (as escape for the next \ ) and the JSON parser will correctly receive \"

Comment: The above comment helps a lot. I am not sure of why Gson only adds a single reversed solidus, when two is needed. but that might be for another question...

Comment: I suspect the problem comes because Gson's serialisation is fine within Java land, but if you directly write that Java string to the client inside a `<script>` tag or something, then it hasn't been correctly escaped again to be valid for Javascript.

Comment: I thought the whole concept oj JSON was it's fantastic language independency, and still there are different ways of parsing it... I have to say I am a bit disappointed. This will require a lot of extra work, to make sure I translate these and possible future Strings correctly. Thank you all guys for helping me see the issue, anyway. I'll take a round with +1's where ever deserved.

Comment: This is not a failing of JSON. The issue is that you are populating a valid JSON string in a Javascript file _without correctly respecting the way Javascript handles strings_. If you retrieved the JSON via AJAX, it would likely be escaped for you and `JSON.parse()` would work fine. You can think of what you did as "serialising the JSON to a JS string", but you did not serialise it correctly. Does that make more sense?