# How can I get Gson's single escaping to play along with Javascript's double escaping of special characters and symbols?

Tags: java, javascript, json, escaping, gson

As a follow up on my previous question: [Why doesn't my attempt to escape quotation marks in JSON work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985054/why-doesnt-my-attempt-to-escape-quotation-marks-in-json-work/22985232#22985232), I would like to know if there is any way to make Gson and Javascript play along when escaping special characters and symbols.

Consider this as a database table string, that I want to display on a web page:

```
I am "literally" hurting inside because this do not work!
```

If I retrieve the string in Java from my database, and use Gson to parse it, it will look like this:

```
'{"text" : "I am \"literally\" hurting inside that this does not work!"}'
```

However, my Javascript function for parsing needs this to display it correctly:

```
'{"text" : "I am \\"literally\\" hurting inside that this does not work!"}'
```

Are there any way to fix this, other then to check for substrings in Java, and adding an extra `\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Unbescape [ http://www.unbescape.org ]

It allows you to escape JavaScript string literals (among other things like HTML, XML, JSON...), so you can pass you GSON string to it simply like:

```
final String escaped = JavaScriptEscape.escapeJavaScript(text);
```

And it will give you the JavaScript-escaped string you need.

Disclaimer, per StackOverflow rules: I'm Unbescape's author.

Comment: Self promotion, ey? :). I'll make sure to check it out as soon as I can. I am working on another project at the moment, as I found a work around to this issue some time ago. Still, if this is a better way, I might adopt it. Please allow for a bit of time, before I get to it.

Comment: Sorry for taking more than a year! I finally got around to review some of my old posts, and this seems to work out really well. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it will work in all the cases:

```
{\"text\" : \"I am \\\"litteraly\\\" hurting inside that this does not work!\"}
```

---

Sample code:

Using `JSONObject`:

```
    String str = "{\"text\" : \"I am \\\"litteraly\\\" hurting inside that this does not work!\"}";

    try {
        System.out.println(new JSONObject(str).getString("text"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Using `Gson`:

```
class Text implements Serializable{
    private String text;
    ...
}

Gson gson = new Gson();

String str = "{\"text\" : \"I am \\\"litteraly\\\" hurting inside that this does not work!\"}";

System.out.println(gson.fromJson(str, Text.class).text);
```

Firefox Firebug plugin snapshot:

[image]

```
    String str = "{\"text\" : \"I am \\\"litteraly\\\" hurting inside that this does not work!\"}";

    try {
        System.out.println(new JSONObject(str).getString("text"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I do not control the data from the database. I am asking for a way to parse what is already there

Comment: Just replace " before parsing.

Comment: You have to escape " that is present in value.

Comment: I have set a replace string, so that \" becomes \\", but I do not think it is a good solution, as I have to do it on every single thing I extract from the database. i am looking for a better, simpler way, built in the parsers, if they exist.

Comment: any solutions connected to configuration of gson?