# JSON parse \" and "

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I would like to parse the following text using Nodejs

```
let html = '{"text":"class=\"minimal\""}'

console.log(JSON.parse(html))
```

How ever it keeps mixing " and " and the result seem like this

```
{"text":"class="minimal""}
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 16
```

Here is the full version

```
{ "text": "\x3ctable class=\"goldprice-view sticky-enabled\"\x3e\n \x3cthead\x3e\x3ctr\x3e\x3cth class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"table_title\"\x3eGiá vàng quốc tế, USD/VND\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/th\x3e\x3cth\x3eBid\x3c/th\x3e\x3cth\x3eAsk\x3c/th\x3e\x3cth\x3eCao nhất\x3c/th\x3e\x3cth\x3eThấp nhất\x3c/th\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\x3c/thead\x3e\n\x3ctbody\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"group_usdvnd odd\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3eUSD/VND \x3cbr /\x3e \x3cspan class=\"size-11\"\x3e(Liên NH)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"bid \"\x3e23,475\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"ask \"\x3e23,693\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"percent\"\x3e-\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"spread\"\x3e-\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n\x3c/tbody\x3e\n\x3c/table\x3e\n", "error": 0, "main_price": "\x3ctable class=\"goldprice-view sticky-enabled\"\x3e\n \x3cthead\x3e\x3ctr\x3e\x3cth class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"table_title\" \x3eGiá vàng trong nước\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/th\x3e\x3cth\x3e\x3cdiv\x3eMua\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/th\x3e\x3cth class=\"last\"\x3e\x3cdiv\x3eBán\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/th\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\x3c/thead\x3e\n\x3ctbody\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"odd\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eAVPL / DOJI HN lẻ\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(nghìn/lượng)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,650\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,800\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"even\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eAVPL / DOJI HN buôn\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(nghìn/lượng)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,660\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,790\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"odd\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eAVPL / DOJI HCM lẻ\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(nghìn/lượng)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,650\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,850\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"even\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eAVPL / DOJI HCM buôn\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(nghìn/lượng)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,660\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,840\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"odd\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eAVPL / DOJI ĐN lẻ\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(nghìn/lượng)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,630\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,900\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"even\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eAVPL / DOJI ĐN buôn\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(nghìn/lượng)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,630\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,900\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"odd\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eNguyên liêu 9999 - HN\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(99.9)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,400\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,600\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"even\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eNguyên liêu 999 - HN\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(99)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,350\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,550\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"odd\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eAVPL / DOJI CT lẻ\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(nghìn/chỉ)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,650\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,800\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n \x3ctr class=\"even\"\x3e\x3ctd class=\"first\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"title clear-block clear size-18 normal\"\x3eAVPL / DOJI CT buôn\x3c/span\x3e\x3cspan class=\"sub-title clear size-13 normal\"\x3e(nghìn/chỉ)\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-0\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,660\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e\x3ctd class=\"goldprice-td goldprice-td-1\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"item-relative\"\x3e48,790\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/td\x3e \x3c/tr\x3e\n\x3c/tbody\x3e\n\x3c/table\x3e\n\x3cp class=\"left p-l-15\" style=\"color:#666666\"\x3e\x3cspan class=\"update-time size-14\"\x3eCập nhập lúc: 16:29 22/06/2020\x3c/span\x3e\x3c/p\x3e", "status": 1 }


{ "text": "<table class="goldprice-view sticky-enabled">
                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 25
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/noy/Work/Test/test node/index.js:135:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: `html = '{"text":"class=\\"minimal\\""}'` - you need to double escape the back slashes to keep them in the string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't my attempt to escape quotation marks in JSON work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985054/why-doesnt-my-attempt-to-escape-quotation-marks-in-json-work)

Comment: let html = '{"text":"class=\"minimal\""}'
this is just demo
I cannot change the text in fact it's a simplify of what I receive from server. I need to parse it to handle each part. But got trouble in this step.

Comment: @noynoy What exactly do you receive from the server? If the server response would contain `{"text":"class=\"minimal\""}`, it would be valid and should work just fine. Without more details we can't help you.

Comment: I updated the question with full detail of what I got from the request. but really. Just need to figure out how to read the  content of thoseunicode encoded

Answer (score 3):

Correct version is following

```js
let html = '{"text":"class=\\"minimal\\""}'

console.log(JSON.parse(html))
```

If you just put `'{"text":"class=\"minimal\""}'` it will results into `'{"text":"class="minimal""}'` which is incorrect for JSON

But if you use `'{"text":"class=\\"minimal\\""}'` it will results into `'{"text":"class=\"minimal\""}'` which is correct for JSON

You can check it by simply 
`console.log('{"text":"class=\"minimal\""}')`
`console.log('{"text":"class=\\"minimal\\""}')`

Comment: sorry, The text '{"text":"class=\\"minimal\\""}' just a simplify of a very long decoded unicode text which I received from server. I need to convert it to object to handle it but got trouble in this step.

Comment: Can you show how you getting this string from server?  By using xmlhttprequest?